# Multiple parameter keyword searches in firefox (or chrome)

Tags: firefox

I love using firefox's (and chrome's) custom keyword searches.  One lookup I often do is a company directory using people's first and last names.  I was wondering if I could substitute 2 parameters like this:

http://internal.mycompany.com/directorySearch?fname=%s&lname=%s (this is a fake url)

so I could do a lookup like this

```
ds ben anderson
```

That is exactly what is described here:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Multiple_parameter_keyword_searches

However, it doesn't seem to work for me.  Can someone either confirm that the instructions in the above link do work (and that I somehow fumbled them) or let me know if there's another way to do it?

Thanks!

ps - if you know a way to do this in chrome, please share that as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Credits to sammio5](http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-tips-tricks/multiple-critiera-using-custom-search-engines-8632.html#post20185):

> Yes, it is possible in Chrome!
>
> I managed to create a really cool search engine for subtitles. I just
>   type: `subs <title> <season> <episode>` and automatically go to the
>   downloadpage for the episode i want. You could even add language
>   parameters or more.
>
> Just add this javascript as the URL in
>   chrome://settings/searchEngines:
>
> > javascript:url='http://www.podnapisi.net/nl/ppodnapisi/search?sT=1&sK=%0s&sTS=%1s&sTE=%2s';parts='%s'.replace(/(%5C%5C)?+/g,
> >     function($0,$1)%7Breturn($1?'+':'qzq')%7D).split('qzq');for(var i=0; i
> >     < parts.length && (url=url.replace(new RegExp('%'+i+'s',
> >     'g'),parts[i]));i++);location=url.replace(/%[0-9]s/g,'')

Comment: This solution (using `javascript:location=<url>`) doesn't work in a new tab, which is a common way to open new web pages in Chrome.

Comment: Javascript snippets "work" in Chrome when pressing cmd + return instead of return, but that's rather awkward because it opens the search in a new tab instead of the current one.