# Custom URL shortcuts in Google Chrome with multiple arguments?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple parameter keyword searches in firefox (or chrome)](https://superuser.com/questions/382631/multiple-parameter-keyword-searches-in-firefox-or-chrome)

I'm trying to create a shortcut for Google Chrome that will allow me to type "`w de foosball`" in the Chrome Omnibox, and have it open the URL http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=foosball.

What I'd *ideally* like to do is create a custom web search engine like so:

```
Name:      My wiki search
Shortcut:  w
URL:       http://%1.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%2
```

But Chrome only allows ***one*** argument for custom search engines ("`%s`"), so I'm looking for some other way to accomplish this.

This would be really helpful for a couple of internal websites, which are of the form "`https://a-b-c.company.com`", where "`a`", "`b`" and "`c`" vary across different applications, and the number of possible combinations is in the thousands.

I've looked for Chrome plugins that will do this, tried using OS X app launchers like Spotlight, Quicksilver and Alfred, tried downloading plugins for said app launchers... and found nothing. It seems like I either need to roll my own Chrome Extension, or use javascript via a bookmark somehow. But am I really the first person that's tried to do this?

Comment: That particular solution (using `javascript:location=<url>`) doesn't work in a new tab, which is how I typically open new web pages in Chrome.